# Is it possible to call wcf net.pipe://<<hostname>> from jquery?

Tags: jquery, wcf, wcf-rest

**I have one scenario:-**

One page like Test.html hosted on server and that page have jquery ajax call and that jquery ajax call use for the call one REST service and that service host in localhost.

That’s service hosted in local machine so that page automatically call the service which is hosted on local machine.

This senior is possible in when we use Web API and WCF REST webhttps binding service but I want that from **net.pipe binding**.

So for that I have two question as per below

**Is It possible to create WCF rest service for net.pipe://<< hostname >> ?**

**So If yes then Is it possible to create client which is consume wcf net.pipe://<< hostname >> service from html jquery ajax call?**

If above two scenario possible then please share link or example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using JQuery?

No.

Using a DotNet Client (yes). (Example below).

JQuery is an abstraction for "web traffic".  So your WCF endpoints need to be web-friendly endpoints.

Named Pipes has nothing to do with "the internet".

"Host" (Server)

```
    <service name="Wcf.BusinessServices.DepartmentBusinessService">


        <endpoint
              address  = "net.pipe://localhost/LocalDepartmentBusinessService"
              binding  = "netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NamedPipeBindingName1"
              contract = "ServiceInterfaces.Managers.IDepartmentManager"    >
        </endpoint>

    </service>
```

"Client"

```
<client>

  <endpoint name="NamedPipeEndPointName"
    address  = "net.pipe://localhost/LocalDepartmentBusinessService"
    binding  = "netNamedPipeBinding" bindingConfiguration="NamedPipeBindingName1"
    contract = "ServiceInterfaces.Managers.IDepartmentManager"  >
  </endpoint>
```

Exists on both sides (Host/Server and Client)

```
<bindings>


  <netNamedPipeBinding>
    <binding name="NamedPipeBindingName1"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferSize="9000000"
                 maxConnections="10"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="9000000"
                 receiveTimeout="00:30:00"
                 transactionFlow="false">
      <security mode="Transport">
      </security>
    </binding>
  </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks, just that I want to know is it possible or not.